# How to split <table> with jQuery on the fly?

Tags: jquery, split, html-table

In order to expose one particular TBODY with cross-browser support, I need to split my `<table>` to 3 tables on the fly and expose the middle one. Is it possible without rebuilding a whole table? Anyone knows relevant tutorials that could help to make it efficiently?

Example. Initially:

```
<table>
<tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        ....
</tbody> 
<tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        ....
</tbody>
<tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        ....
</tbody>
</table>
```

Result:

```
<table>
<tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        ....
</tbody>
</table>
<table> 
<tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        ....
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        ....
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are after, but you could to the following with jQuery.

```
$('tbody').hide();
$('tbody:odd').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/NybeH/

This hides all the `tbody` elements and then shows only the odd ones.  Fyi... odd works here because it's a zero-based count.